# DB2: Insert new rows and ignore duplicates

Tags: db2

I have about 100 rows to insert in a table - Some of them have already been inserted before and some of them have not

This is my insert that works fine if the primary key doesn't exist.. I'm going to run this 100 time with different values each time.. However, if the primary key exist, it fails and stop future commands to run.

How to ignore the failure and keep going or simply ignore duplicates?

```
INSERT  INTO  MY_TABLE 
   VALUES( 12342, 'fdbvdfb', 'svsdv', '5019 teR','' , 'saa', 'AL',35005 , 'C', 37, '0',368 , 'P', '2023-02-13', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-20','' , 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'JFK', '', null, 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '', '', '',2385 ,2 , '', 'N', '2023-01-16', '2023-01-20', '', NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Y', 'Test', 'Test', '', 'N', 'Test', '')
```

This is the error:

```
SQL0803N One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "XPS01ME1" constrains
```

Insert IGNORE into throws:

```
The use of the reserved word "IGNORE" following "" is not valid.
```

If it can help I'm using WinSQL 10.0.157.697

Comment: Since you are asking solely about DB2, I removed the mysql tag.

Comment: what platform and version?  What are your tables column names?  What's the primary key?

Comment: should have said "what platform and version (of Db2)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what platform and version of Db2, so I'll point you to the Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW) documentation for the [`MERGE` statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-merge)...

Since I don't know your table or column names, I'll just give you an example with dummy names.

```
merge into MYTABLE as tgt
using (select * 
        from table( values(1,1,'CMW',5,1)
                  ) tmp ( tblKey, fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
      ) as src
on src.tblKey = tgt.tblekey
when not matched then 
   insert ( tblKey, fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
     values ( src.tblKey, src.fld1, src.fld2, src.fld3, src.fld4);
```

You're basically building a temporary table on the fly of one row
`table( values(1,1,'CMW',5,1) ) tmp ( tblKey, fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)`

Then if there's no matching record via `on src.tblKey = tgt.tblekey` you do an insert.

Note that while you could do this 100 times, it is a much better performing solution to do all 100 rows at a time.

```
merge into MYTABLE as tgt
using (select * 
        from table( values (1,1,'CMW1',5,1)
                          , (2,11,'CMW2',50,11)
                          , (3,21,'CMW3',8,21)
                         -- , <more rows here>
                  ) tmp ( tblKey, fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
      ) as src
on src.tblKey = tgt.tblekey
when not matched then 
   insert ( tblKey, fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
     values ( src.tblKey, src.fld1, src.fld2, src.fld3, src.fld4);
```

Optionally, you could create an actual temporary table, insert the 100 rows (preferably in a single insert) and then use `MERGE`.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with a compound statement like below:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)@

BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23505' BEGIN END;
  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID) VALUES (1);
END@

BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23505' BEGIN END;
  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
END@

BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23505' BEGIN END;
  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID) VALUES (4);
END@

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE@
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NOTMrddo)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you ignore an error in db2 --

*note, this is not the correct sqlstate for your problem -- replace with the one you need*

```
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23505'         
   BEGIN  -- ignore error for duplicate value 
   END;
```

Documented here
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=procedure-ignoring-condition-in-sql

Comment: The error I'm getting doesn't have a SQLSTATE: SQL0803N  One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "XPS01ME1" constrains

Your statement also throws: SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "HANDLER" following "" is not valid.

Comment: That's not going to work from an interactive query tool as it would appear the OP is using.

Comment: @Charles -- This is the only way to "skip" errors in DB2 as far as I know.